# Is polar decomposition commutative for diagonal matrices?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, svd

I did a error while understanding about the polar decompositon.
I thought polar decomposition is `PU`, but it is `UP`. While trying to understand what went wrong, I realized that it is somewhat commutative for the inputs I am giving to it because of which I could not realize about this big mistake.
It would be great if someone can explain about this so that I can understand whether it is commutative for all diagonal matrices?
Are there any polar decompositon formula where polar decomposition is `PU`? Thank you for great help.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import polar
A= np.array([[-2, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, -2, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, -2, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, -2]])
U, P = polar(A)
print(U)
print(P)
A1 = U @ P
print(A1)
A2 = P @ U
print(A2)
are_equal = np.allclose(A1, A2)
print("Are matrix equal:", are_equal)
```

Comment: It is commutative when $A$ is symmetric (or Hermitian if complex)

Comment: Thank you @Exodd for the response. What is Hermitian?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix